Can anyone help identify this resistor?
To my eyes the stripes look like gold-gold-black, but that doesn't make any sense. Any help would be appreciated.





Was there any Reference designator next to the component on the PCB silkscreen? If so, that might identify if is a resistor or possibly something else.

It was labeled with an R so I'm fairly certain it's a resistor.

It isssssss.. an ex-resistor. If they hadn't soldered it to the board it would be pushing up the daisies. Anyway, there's not enough left of it to tell just by looking at it. Best bet would be to find a schematic. Do you have a make and model number of what it's in?

Looking at the final picture, there is part of a line in a darker colour which could have been a 4th band, but due to the "charring" not entirely sure.

@ChesterGillon Even assuming you're correct, that would mean the color code would begin with either gold or black since those are the two ends, and I've never heard of a color code starting with black before.

@GodJihyo Nah it's just stunned is all. It's from a GEDI-G GD-2808 speaker.

I made an educated guess based on the fact that the voltage regulator this resistor was feeding has an operating range of 5–15v, i made an educated guess that the circuit was drawing 100mA at 5v and went with an 82 ohm resistor. So far all seems good, so i think my guess was accurate. I also made sure to go with a much larger resistor than the original so that it doesn't burn up again.

If the component was feeding a voltage regulator and it wasn't being used as a current sensor then there is a good chance it was a fusible resistor - that is, a resistor that acts as a fuse without being a fire hazard.
